# how to present ViewController on SWRevealViewController with TabbarController in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am redirecting my app to specific view controllers on notification click in `AppDelegate` and for that, I am using setting root view controller method but in my case, open tab bar that base view that is `SWRevealViewController` with `TabbarController` of the app and on that present request view controller.

**here is what I tried so far:**

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homepage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")
self.window?.rootViewController = homepage

let rootView = self.window!.rootViewController

let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Ride", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"payAfterPostRequestViewController") as! payAfterPostRequestViewController
rootView!.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**here is what I get by above code:**

> *Attempt to present <****.payAfterPostRequestViewController: 0x1078e7600> on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!*

Comment: you have a very bad UI in your app, side menu is not used with tabBar, but is that's was required. you need t change the approach since the viewcontroller you set in app delegate is not yet loaded in the new hierarchy, so set a value in the view controller and verify in viewDidAppear is set then do the present textview controller. or find the top most viewcontroller in your view hierarchy and present the needed view controller

Comment: you said side menu is not used with sidebar but what if that's clients requirement and also there are lot of application out there that is using the same ui as I'm doing. about your answer can you post it in the answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

may be is not the best way to do it but is almost how I would solve that madness.
first try to set a var in the presented viewController

```
var shouldPresentOtherVC = false
override function viewDidAppear(){
  super.viewDidAppear()
  if shoulPresentOtherVC{
  //do the presentation here
```

then proceed as you do but omit the present part

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homepage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")
self.window?.rootViewController = homepage
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

if the presented viewcontroller is not necesary to tho from specific VC then I used this code. for present the vc.

```
    extension UIWindow {
    func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        var top = self.rootViewController
        while true {
            if let presented = top?.presentedViewController {
                top = presented
            } else if let nav = top as? UINavigationController {
                top = nav.visibleViewController
            } else if let tab = top as? UITabBarController {
                top = tab.selectedViewController
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        return top
    }
}
```

to find the topViewController and then  after this line

```
self.window?.rootViewController = homepage`
```

add this.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Ride", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"payAfterPostRequestViewController") as! payAfterPostRequestViewController
self.window?.topViewController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```